# Knight in Shining Armor - Idioms

Tags: idioms

while working on some translations I ran across the phrase: 輝く鎧の騎士.  A character was refered to as this.  Google tells me it translates to "knight in shining armor". 
My question is thus:  Is that the idiomatic equivalent of the phrase in English, and if not what is?

Answer (score 4):

In Japan, you often hear 「白馬{はくば}の王子様{おうじさま}」or「白馬{はくば}に乗{の}った王子様{おうじさま}」to represent a gallant prince saving a damsel in distress.

Your example seems more of a literal translation of the English idiom but I'm uncertain.

Comment: I think it is, as the character described literally wears shiny armor.